# problems when working on a game just like fruit ninja

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, touch

i want to make a similar game to fruit ninja. 
at first I have: 
a GameScene(a multi layer scene which adds different GameModeLayers and  a PauseLayer as children), 
a ClassicGameModeLayer, which is only a container for sprite iVar of Fruit class. isTouchEnabled = NO, and no game logic behind. 
a Fruit class, which contains a CCSprite *fruit and int score. conform to CCTouchDelegate and handles all the game logic behind. (just like the sample Spider code in book "Learn.iPhone.and.iPad.Cocos2D.Game.Development")

Then i have a problem. i can only slice one fruit at a time and touch is available only after the fruit shows up.

i have 2 other models designed today. one is to put the touch handling code in ClassicGameModeLayer, and also contains a CCArray of Fruit, keep the movement of Fruit inside Fruit class.

and the other model is to create a CCArray of CCSprite fruits inside the Fruit class, with all the game logic(ClassicGameLayer still does nothing)

i don't know if they are achievable. i am currently coding the first one and crashes somehow. you guys have any better ideas? is there a common approach to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The touch only shows up after the fruit appears because the fruit is the only object that responds to touches.  Your app can't respond until the fruit exists.

Take a look at [Ray Wenderlich's](http://www.raywenderlich.com/?s=cocos2d) tutorials for creating Cocos2D-iPhone apps.

My suggestion is this:

- have the layer respond to touches
- create a "FruitManager" Singleton that holds all the fruit
- when you touch the screen, `[[FruitManager sharedFruitManager] allFruits]` will give you a list of the fruits to see if the user has "touched" through one of them.

Ray's Wack-A-Mole game should get you close to what you're doing.  His Ninja/Ghost game also has rules for intercepting projectiles - just use touches instead.

Comment: that's a good resource, thanks man. i think i have to finish the book first though